# Java - For loop seems to execute past it's termination condition

Tags: java, for-loop

I have debugged this code and it appears to run a for loop even though the termination condition is met.

This program takes two types of input:

Line 1 - How many data points there are following (N)

Lines 2 to N - The data points

The program should then print the smallest difference between all of the data points.

So, for instance, a sample input would be (on separate lines): 3 5 8 9

There are 3 data points (5 8 9), and the smallest difference is between 8 and 9, so the program should return 1.

I am trying to build the program in a way in which the data points are populated into an array at the same time as the comparisons are made. Obviously I could separate those concerns, but I am experimenting. Here it is:

```
package com.m3c.vks.test;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;

class Solution {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = in.nextInt(); //How many data points there will be
        int strengthArray[] = new int[N]; //Initialise the array to be of length = N, the first input line
        int tempStrengthDifference=99999; //junk difference set arbitrarily high - bad practice I know
        int lowestStrengthDifference=99999;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) //Go through all elements of array
        {
            strengthArray[i] = in.nextInt(); //read a value for the ith element
            System.out.println("i: " + i); //test
            if (i > 0) //do not execute the next for loop if i = 0 as cannot evaluate sA[-1]
            {
                for (int j = i - 1; j < 1; j--) // **this is line 20** from wherever the array has populated up to, work backwards to compare the numbers which have been fed in thus far
                {
                    System.out.println("j: " + j); //test
                    tempStrengthDifference = Math.abs(strengthArray[i] - strengthArray[j]); //finding the difference between two values
                    if (tempStrengthDifference < lowestStrengthDifference) //store the lowest found thus far in lowestSD
                    {
                        lowestStrengthDifference = tempStrengthDifference;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(lowestStrengthDifference);
    }
}
```

Everything is fine up until when i = 1 on line 20. At this point, j is set to i - 1 = 0 and the difference is found. However, when the for loop comes back around again, the termination condition of j < 1 is not met, and instead the loop continues to set j = -1, at which point it throws an out of bounds error as it clearly cannot evaluate strengthArray[-1]

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: `j = -1` _does met_ `j < 1` as `-1 < 1`.

Comment: Thanks, I've added **this is line 20** so ctrl+f for that.

Comment: @tkausl Yes, you're correct. The termination condition is met, so should it not break the loop?

Comment: @JoshuaViggiani That's the condition to continue the loop, not stop it. You've written, while j is less than one, continue. So it continues on 0, -1, -2, -3, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your loop: `for (int j = i - 1; j < 1; j--)`

You start with `j = 0` when `i == 1`  and thus `j < 1` is ok.

The next iteration has `j = -1` (`0-1`) and hence you get the problem.

Do you mean to use `j >= 0` as your loop condition instead? Note that the second parameter is *not a termination condition* but a *continuation condition*, i.e. as long as that condition is met the loop will execute.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense. I did not realise that it was a continuation condition as I'm still in a c# mindset. I will more carefully scrutinise the documentation in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaViggiani "I'm still in a c# mindset." - Afaik C# loops work the same way, don't they? In general loops operate on a "continuation" condition (e.g. `while(true)` and the like) and explicit stop conditions normally are used in conjunction with `break` (e.g. `if( stop ) break;`).

Comment: Seems like you're right. Not sure where I got the termination condition paradigm from

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind your failure is the inner loop variable change. 
When i=1, j=0 and after executing the loop once, J is decremented, and thus j becomes - 1. The condition j<1 is satisfied since you have written j--, change it to j++ and you should be fine.